# Импортирование сторонних библиотек в ходе выполнения Python EXE файла

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемкой, собрал .py файл в .exe. В коде есть строка, которая отвечает за импорт сторонних библиотек из папки packages, по мере их необходимости.

**Собственно сама строчка:**

```
 exec(f"from {lib} import *", globals())
```

И допустим поступила команда, что нужно импортировать файл/библиотеку/модуль smth.py.

Получается, что программа должна выполнить строку так:

```
exec("from packages.smth import *", globals())
```

Но при попытке выполнить её выдаёт ошибку:

```
  File "shelly.py", line 35, in initLibs
     exec(f"from {lib} import *", globals())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packages'
```

Если запустить чисто .py файл, то всё прекрасно импортируется и работает.

Comment: Вообще, есть importlib, незачем через exec извращаться. По вопросу - возможно нужно будет текущую папку добавить в переменную окружения PYTHONPATH (возможно из самого скрипта).

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за совет с importlib. чего то я эту библиотеку мимо глаз пропустил. обязательно попробую.

Comment: importlib не спасает, у него имя импортируемой библиотеки задаётся в переменную, ссылаясь на которую, можно вызывать функции из модуля.

Comment: Ну вы же то же самое и пытаетесь сделать через exec.

Comment: Если при выполнение кода я импортирую модуль через exec( ), то далее, через этот exec( ) можно использовать функции из модуля.

Comment: Если импортировать через importlib, то потом без exec можно использовать функции из модуля. Не вижу проблемы, по-моему так даже лучше.

Comment: Ну или через exec, если нужно, точно так же globals туда передаете.